# SEO: URL for detail page, include categories or not?

Tags: url, url-rewriting, seo, url-routing

I'm working on a new advert website and want to implement some good SEO URLs.

I got category URLs like:

```
/category
/category/sub-category
```

This seems ok. What about detail pages?

Option 1:

```
/announcements-and-notices/announcements-various/15880/suscipit-dis-molestie-malesuada-vestibulum-ut.html
```

Option 2:

```
/adverts/15880/suscipit-dis-molestie-malesuada-vestibulum-ut.html
```

In reality my website has a pretty long URLs due to multiple areas you can shop. So it would become:

```
/en/area-name/announcements-and-notices/announcements-various/15880/suscipit-dis-molestie-malesuada-vestibulum-ut.html

/en/area-name/adverts/15880/suscipit-dis-molestie-malesuada-vestibulum-ut.html
```

Which detail page would be a better URL? The first option seems to be better if the product has no long/good title. The second seems better as its the most relevant one and shortest especially with long category names.

I would like to hear your thoughts!

EDIT:

I found this two google docs:

http://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fwebmasters%2Fdocs%2Fsearch-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf&ei=lXyaT6T_L8zR4QSM4c2qDw&usg=AFQjCNEMj8KHxhxQz9cMLoMxMDiLdrAbJw

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=76329

I think I will be going for /adverts. Anyone disagree?

Answer (score 0):

i have seen many of SEO analysts miss something about optimizing their webpage and that is your page will be optimized for only some keywords not all keywords. it is not important how length is your URL. you should first analyze whether the contents in your webpage is rich enough to have such URL with these keywords or not. if the answer for every keyword is yes then the more length will give you the more rank.

Comment: url length is important. the shorter the better, or you're going to give up some seo juice to url shorteners...unless you run your own, but that still will not prevent users from using a different shortener.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can even set your pages up in a way to use only the slug and skip the id, such as:

```
/adverts/suscipit-dis-molestie-malesuada-vestibulum-ut
```

or even just:

```
/suscipit-dis-molestie-malesuada-vestibulum-ut
```

like this and refer straight to the *adverts* controller and the advert itself, which has this slug assigned to it (the one with id 15880).

This way you'll have nice and clean URLs. Just assign and keep an **unique** slug for each advert and handle it using .htaccess, or dynamically inside the code of your site, if the system allows it.

Cheers.